# How to use indexOf with datalist options

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, indexof, html-datalist

When a `stateName` (i.e. Vermont) is selected from the `datalist`, I want to display the state abbreviation name `abbrName` (i.e. VT) from the `datalist` `option id=` in the results.

My current code searches the `datalist` `options` with the index value derived from the `object`, but the problem is the `datalist` and the `object` are not sorted the same way, so the index value `z` yields the wrong result.

Should I search the `datalist` with `IndexOf`?  How can I find the `datalist` index position?

```js
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function result() {
  var a = n.value;
  document.getElementById("stateName").innerHTML = a;
  myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
    var q = document.getElementById("stateName").innerHTML;
    if (e.properties.id == q) {
      document.getElementById("statePosition").innerHTML = z;
      document.getElementById("statePopulation").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.population;
      document.getElementById("abbrName").innerHTML = document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option')[z].getAttribute('id');
    }
  });
}

myObj = {
  "type": "A",
  "info": [{
      "item": "1",
      "properties": {
        "id": "Vermont",
        "population": "620,000"
      }
    },
    {
      "item": "2",
      "properties": {
        "id": "Alabama",
        "population": "4,780,000"
      }
    },
    {
      "item": "3",
      "properties": {
        "id": "California",
        "population": "39,540,000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="" option="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="result()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
  <option id="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option id="CA">California</option>
  <option id="VT">Vermont</option>
</datalist>

<p>Object index position: <span id="statePosition"></span></p>
<p>Object result (state name): <span id="stateName"></span></p>
<p>Object result (population): <span id="statePopulation"></span></p>
<p>Datalist index position (state abbreviation position): <span id="abbrPosition"></span></p>
<p>Datalist "option id" (state abbreviation name): <span id="abbrName"></span></p>
```

Comment: Instead of an array, why don't you use an object whose keys are the IDs of the values of the options in the datalist?

Comment: Interesting idea, however in reality I'm retrieving the data directly from an external JSON.

Comment: So? You can easily write code that converts the array into an object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into that. Any other solutions you would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it yields the wrong result.

You might change the order of the options and the array to the same values to same index.

---

Or you could seach for the value in the data list and take the `id` as `abbrName`.

```
function result() {
    var a = n.value;
    document.getElementById("stateName").innerHTML = a;
    myObj.info.forEach(function (e, z) {
        var q = document.getElementById("stateName").innerHTML;
        if (e.properties.id == q) {
            document.getElementById("statePosition").innerHTML = z;
            document.getElementById("statePopulation").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.population;
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("abbrName").innerHTML = [].find.call(document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option'), ({ value }) => value === a).id;
}
```

It uses the array like object of

```
document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option')
```

an borrows [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) from an array and takes the above array like object as `this` objects together with [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

As `find` callback

```
({ value }) => value === a
```

a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) takes place, where just a single property of the iterating object is taken and then compared with the given value.

If the comparision returns `true`, the object is found and returned from `find`. Then it takes the `id` propery.

Comment: Yes, however I don't want order to matter for the options or array.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. As a beginner, if I want to read more how would you describe this solution, key terms, etc.? ({ value }) => value === a).id;